# Buddypress Add unserialized Profile Fields in Members Loop

Tags: custom-field, customization, buddypress, profiles

I'm trying to show profile fields with **checkboxes and drop-downs** in the members directory loop.

**Example: Next to each member in the directory I want to show the Gender they selected**

This code works for text fields:

```
echo xprofile_get_field_data('Full Name', bp_get_member_user_id());
```

BUT **how do I echo profile fields for drop-downs or checkboxes** (unserialized data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe xprofile_get_field_data is unserializing the data for you, but it is still in an array.

xprofile_get_field_data can return an array or a comma-separated string.

```
xprofile_get_field_data( $field, $user_id = 0, $multi_format = 'array' )
```

@param string $multi_format

- How should array data be returned?
- 'comma' if you want a  comma-separated string
- 'array' if you want an  array

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is this code for a single user which I have to specify his user Id? Because I want this to output the Gender selectbox field for all members. I'm making gender a requirement so I need it for everyone to show in the members loop.

Comment: Also, where would I specify the actual name of the field?

Comment: Thanx, Ive got it working now

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the new plugin "Buddypress Xprofile Custom Fields Type" http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-xprofile-custom-fields-type/

Comment: Thanx mirage, its a useful plugin but im looking for a way to unserialize profile data and display it.

Comment: found this solution on buddypress.org:
$platforms = xprofile_get_field_data('Plattformen');
$data = xprofile_format_profile_field('checkbox', $platforms);
echo $data;

Comment: That didnt work. Did you test it yourself? Is there more discussion about it that I can have a look at?

Comment: Here is the link: http://buddypress.org/community/groups/how-to-and-troubleshooting/forum/topic/calling-specific-profile-fields-individually/?topic_page=2&num=15

Comment: I think the process has chaned in the new BP as this isnt working

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Wrap the profile fields in a profile loop within the members loop and the data will output properly, just as it would inside of the profile loop.

```
<?php while ( bp_members() ) : bp_the_member(); ?>
<?php bp_member_profile_data( 'field=Gender' );?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```